# Why does git think I have a sparse checkout? "You are in a sparse checkout with 100% of tracked files present."

Tags: git

Background: recently setup a new laptop, and zip'd my repo up from the previous laptop and unzipped on the new laptop. Everything else seems to be working fine. I've never made a sparse checkout in this repo or on this machine.

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

You are in a sparse checkout with 100% of tracked files present.

$ git sparse-checkout list
warning: this worktree is not sparse (sparse-checkout file may not exist)

$ tree .git/info
.git/info
├── exclude
└── refs
```

I'm using worktrees, so I created a new worktree but it gives the same results. The above commands were run from the main worktree dir.

I found the command to disable a sparse checkout, but it doesn't appear to affect anything:

```
$ git sparse-checkout disable
$ git sparse-checkout disable --global
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

You are in a sparse checkout with 100% of tracked files present.
```

I'm pretty sure I could simply reclone the repo to make it go away, but I want to make sure this doesn't keep happening.

#### Update

Running `git config --get --bool core.sparsecheckout` does print `true`, and the `git config --list --show-origin` shows that it's coming from the local `.git/config` file where I can see it's indeed `true`. After running `git sparse-checkout disable` and immediately `cat`'g the file, I can see the value remains unchanged. Permissions on that file are `644` which I believe is ok.

While looking at `.git/config` closer, I saw `extensions.worktreeConfig = true`, though I don't have a corresponding `config.worktree` (I am using worktrees though). I ran `git config extensions.worktreeConfig false` and that value IS reflected in the file. Yet, if I run `git sparse-checkout disable` again, it resets `extensions.worktreeConfig` back to `true`.

On a whim, I ran `git config core.sparsecheckout false` and that seems to have made the expected change -- and even better, `extensions.worktreeConfig` retained its value. And yes, `git status` no longer mentions a "sparse checkout", which is great.

This is all on git v2.28.0. The docs page for `git sparse-checkout` states: ***THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL***, so maybe I should take them seriously and consider this a bug :)

Comment: `git status` prints this message if `core.sparsecheckout` is configured to `true` or anything that maps to true (e.g., to `1`). So `git config --get --bool core.sparsecheckout` should print `true`. Use `git config --list --show-origin` to see where the `true` setting is set—but note that `git sparse-checkout disable` should have *cleared* the setting. This is puzzling.

Comment: Updated my post since the comment was too long, but I think it's all fixed up now. If you want to answer with this same comment, I'll accept it and not feel bad about it, since it led me down the right path. Otherwise, accept this vote and my thanks!

Comment: This was driving me crazy, your question (and answer contained within) helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments (and some poking around in the Git source), I can say that this seems to be a bug in some of the new sparse support, in terms of its interaction with a feature that first went into Git 2.20, namely `extensions.worktreeConfig`, and what went out with Git 2.28.

To fix it, you should be able to run:

```
git config core.repositoryformatversion 1
```

(or, you can do what you did ).

#### Details

The `extensions.worktreeConfig` setting is, or at least was originally, intended for use with `git worktree`.  It causes Git to read *two* local (repository-specific) configuration files: the file named `config` in the `$GIT_DIR` (i.e., `.git/config`), and the file named `config.worktree`.

By itself, this feature seems useless: why read two separate files for one configuration?  The trick here is that `.git/config` applies to *all added work-trees* while *each added work-tree has its own* `config.worktree` file.  So you can configure different settings in each added work-tree: anything you want configured for *all* worktrees attached to this repository goes in `.git/config`, and anything you want in one *particular* work-tree attached to this repository goes in `$GIT_DIR/worktrees/<id>/config.worktree` (assuming it's an added work-tree and not the main one: the main one doesn't have a `worktrees/` subdirectory so that one's file would be in `$GIT_DIR/config.worktree`).

The interaction with sparse checkout itself is straightforward: sparse checkout is meant to be per-worktree.  So any time you use `git sparse-checkout`, Git tries to turn on the per-work-tree extension and set the configuration in each work-tree separately.  But there's a bug here, not related directly to sparse checkout.

There is a much older setting in Git called `core.repositoryformatversion`.  This setting predates Git 1.0 (the oldest tag that contains the commit that adds it is `v0.99.9l`, which was rc4 for Git 1.0).  This setting was set at zero from the time it was created (2005) until `extensions.*` were created back in 2015 ([commit `00a09d57eb8a041e6a6b0470c53533719c049bab`(https://github.com/git/git/commit/00a09d57eb8a041e6a6b0470c53533719c049bab)).  *All* extensions (`extensions.*` settings) are *supposed* to require `core.repositoryformatversion` to be set to `1`, so as to enable them.  But in fact, they didn't.

For Git version 2.28.0, Git added code to *check* the above requirement.  If `core.repositoryformatversion` was set to *zero*, all extensions were disabled.  Once set to 1, the extensions become enabled.

Unfortunately, programs like `git sparse-checkout` would *use* the extensions, without first *setting* `core.repositoryformatversion`.  Before Git 2.28, this worked.  So all these experimental commands worked, as far as things went.  But then the long-standing bug got fixed, which broke everything using extensions.<sup>1</sup>

In Git 2.29, I believe Git either notices and warns about the wrong `repositoryformatversion` setting, or fixes it automatically.  (I have not checked or tested this.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The main other user of extensions is probably the partial clone stuff, enabled via `extensions.partialClone` and `extensions.partialCloneRemote`.  The others are `extensions.objectFormat`, `extensions.preciousObjects`, and of course `extensions.worktreeConfig`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.